# How to access form inputs in react js with nested object

Tags: forms, reactjs

I'm working a **react form** using the **controlled inputs** to access the change on the form inputs. It contained lot of fields but i haven't posted all the fields.

```
import React from 'react';
import Links from './Links.jsx';
import axios from 'axios';
import Dialog from 'react-bootstrap-dialog';
import {Typeahead} from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';
import Autocomplete from 'react-autocomplete';

import style from './app.css';

class AddNewEmployee extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            firstName : '',
            middleName : ''
        }
        this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this);
    }

    handleUserInput(){
        const name = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
             [name]: value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className = "col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" 
            placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstName"
            value={this.state.firstName} onChange={(event) => this.handleUserInput(event)}>
            </input>
            </div>
            <div className = "col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" 
            placeholder="Enter First Name" name="middleName"
            value={this.state.middleName} onChange={(event) => this.handleUserInput(event)}>
            </input>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default AddNewEmployee;
```

The above code is working fine so far, but i got a requirement to keep an **nested object** to save the form input values.

But i'm missing some thing here how to handle the user input on form elements.
How shall we handle the user input when we have a nested object.

```
import React from 'react';
import Links from './Links.jsx';
import axios from 'axios';
import Dialog from 'react-bootstrap-dialog';
import {Typeahead} from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';
import Autocomplete from 'react-autocomplete';

import style from './app.css';

class AddNewEmployee extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            employee : {
                firstName : '',
                middleName : ''
            }
        }
        this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this);
    }

    handleUserInput(){
        // here how to handle those input changes
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className = "col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" 
            placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstName"
            value={this.state.employee.firstName} onChange={(event) => this.handleUserInput(event)}>
            </input>
            </div>
            <div className = "col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" 
            placeholder="Enter First Name" name="middleName"
            value={this.state.employee.middleName} onChange={(event) => this.handleUserInput(event)}>
            </input>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default AddNewEmployee;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
handleUserInput(e) {
    // Option #1 (mutable data)
    let {employee} = this.state;
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    employee[name] = value;
    this.setState({
      employee
    });

    // Option #2 (immutable data)
    const { employee } = this.state;
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      employee: {
        ...employee,
        [name] : value
      }
    });
  }
```

Also, since you are binding `handleUserInput` in the constructor, you can simplify `onChange={(event) => this.handleUserInput(event)}` to `onChange={this.handleUserInput}`

Comment: handleUserInput(e) {
    // Option #1 (mutable data)
    let {employee} = this.state;// Is it correct or else do we have to use this.state.employee instead of this.state}

Comment: `let {employee} = this.state` is the same as  `let employee = this.state.employee` if that is your question? It's an ES6 feature called "destructuring".